# Spring websocket with stomp security - every user can subscribe to any other users queue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websocket, stomp

I created a simple app that uses the websockets mechanism of spring 4.
I use in my app an activemq broker.

In my simple test i create 10 messages for a user named "Alejando" (user/alejandro/queue/greetings)

When i log in with "Alejando" and subscribe to that queue:

```
  stompClient.subscribe('/user/alejandro/queue/greetings', function(greeting){
                  showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
  });
```

I indeed receive all the 10 messages that were enqued for alejandro.

The problem is when i log in with a different user named "evilBart" and subscribe to the queue of alejandro i receive the messages as well?

How can i enforce security for that? I would like that a user can only subscribe to it's own queue.

Thanks!

my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/","/topic","/user/");     
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take two options.

1. Simply remove "/user/" from config.enableStompBrokerRelay.
   Spring message will automatically prefix.

   convertAndSendToUser is not for broker relay.

[See org.springframework.messaging.simp.user packages source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/user)

Default user prefix is '/user/'. 
 You can change it with config.setUserDestinationPrefix()

2. Override two methods and handle it from ChannelInterceptor

Methods:

configureClientInboundChannel

configureClientOutboundChannel

Answer (score 1):

Check this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282138/websocket-how-to-push-a-message-to-a-target-user/24912748#24912748): you have to authenticate the user via HTTP using Spring Security, and then send message to users using the SimpMessageTemplate.convertAndSendToUser() method.

Comment: But that doesn't really help.  When you use `SimpMessageTemplate.convertAndSendToUser`, if you look at the code, it literally just prefixes '/user/{username}' and then uses the `SimpMessageTemplate.convertAndSend` method.  It does not actually address the security concern.

Comment: Yes, it does: that's a special queue where a unique sessionId of the user is appended to the destination and transparently removed by the broker.Try it and verify that only the originating user is able to receive the messages sent there: all the other clients are not.

Comment: Check out more details and code in my example here: Maybe I am missing something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004081/springmvc-websockets-messaging-user-authentication-with-spring-security | If you are right, I will just nuke my question as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer there, let me know if it solves the problem and if yes, please accept it!